# AutoComplete TextBox in ASP.Net without using AJAX AutoCompleteExtender and Web Services

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

Any example on implementing an `AutoComplete TextBox` in ASP.Net which gets data from database, and doesn't use `AutoCompleteExtender` from Ajax toolkit, also not using Web/Wcf service for requesting data.

For example with `jQuery` and `PHP`, i could just use the $.ajax function, passing a url where PHP just returns a `JSON` object.

Comment: This  can be done if your php page either return json or xml to conusme in jquer.ajax function in asp.net page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to do it in PHP, the same could be used in asp.net.
You don't need to use a webservice. Just a PageMethod would suffice.

Refer: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Since you mention jQuery, this function could return data as required jquery-autocompelete.

But once you receive the list of suggestions for autocomplete, you could very well write the javascript to show it yourself too.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult without using any `extender` or `jquery-autocompelete`
Also you will need to create some server side method that will return `json` form you server side method after querying the data base.

Comment: Although I didn't down vote, I suspect you say "Not possible" without those two earned you the downvote. After all if an extension can do it using javascript, you can very well write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery-autocomplete and to get data from server you can use Generic Handler (.ashx) to get JSON data from server.
In source give path to .ashx page and in handler write JSON data in response stream.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/16/httphandler-json-data/